# R dataframe: setting values in columns to NA based on them being less than a predetermined number

Tags: r, replace, subset

given the following data frame below:

```
>head(ethn)    
    caucasian   asian       latino
    8.28E-27    1.00E+00    1.00E+00
    7.23E-01    6.22E-01    7.48E-01
    2.73E-01    1.60E-01    1.00E+00
    1.09E-04    3.16E-01    4.74E-02
    7.99E-01    6.80E-01    7.37E-01
    1.00E+00    1.00E+00    1.00E+00
    1.00E+00    1.00E+00    1.00E+00
```

How do I set all values less than 0.30 in all columns to NA?
It is a much larger dataframe but I am just giving this as a short example.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> ethn[ethn < 0.3] <- NA
> ethn
  caucasian asian latino
1        NA 1.000  1.000
2     0.723 0.622  0.748
3        NA    NA  1.000
4        NA 0.316     NA
5     0.799 0.680  0.737
6     1.000 1.000  1.000
7     1.000 1.000  1.000
```

Answer (score 1):

The`.default` method for the `is.na<-` function succeeds with data.frames:

```
> is.na(ethn) <- ethn <0.3
> ethn
  caucasian asian latino
1        NA 1.000  1.000
2     0.723 0.622  0.748
3        NA    NA  1.000
4        NA 0.316     NA
5     0.799 0.680  0.737
6     1.000 1.000  1.000
7     1.000 1.000  1.000
```

And looking at the code, before compilation it was exactly what @Jilber offered.

```
`is.na<-.default`
function (x, value) 
{
    x[value] <- NA
    x
}
```